# Debouncing a function on Dropdown JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdowns where the selected value from 1st Dropdown will populate the data in the 2nd Dropdown which is associated with that selected value. 
I am populating the data on close event of dropdown. Clicking on All value multiple times hangs the browser. So i tried implementing debounce function in my code. But the result is the same and the browser is still becoming unresponsive.

Here is my JQuery Code.

```
    function throttle(func, wait, options) {
        var context, args, result;
        var timeout = null;
        var previous = 0;
        if (!options) options = {};
        var later = function () {
            previous = options.leading === false ? 0 : Date.now();
            timeout = null;
            result = func.apply(context, args);
            if (!timeout) context = args = null;
        };
        return function () {
            var now = Date.now();
            if (!previous && options.leading === false) previous = now;
            var remaining = wait - (now - previous);
            context = this;
            args = arguments;
            if (remaining <= 0 || remaining > wait) {
                if (timeout) {
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = null;
                }
                previous = now;
                result = func.apply(context, args);
                if (!timeout) context = args = null;
            } else if (!timeout && options.trailing !== false) {
                timeout = setTimeout(later, remaining);
            }
            return result;
        };
    };
```

```
$('#drpTestPlanAssociation').data("kendoMultiSelectBox").bind("close", throttle(function (e) {
                AreaDetails.onTestPlanSelectChange();
            },1000));
```

Comment: kendo jQuery has its own [throttle](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/throttle), you might want to try that too?

Comment: @shrys Ok. How can i bind the close function with kendo throttle function here ?

Comment: same way you've done with your `throttle` method, you can replace it with  `kendo.throttle`

Comment: had any luck with `kendo.throttle`?

Comment: @shrys Trying my hands on it. Still stress testing on the dropdown on dev tools profile testing.

Comment: @shrys No luck :(  The dropdown is still freezing on selecting all the values from the dorpdown

Comment: @shrys My dropdown is taking value with no lag and without any performance impact. But my browser is becoming unresponsive due to the filter property in Kendo dropdown. Is there any workaround for that ?

Comment: sorry, haven't worked much with the controls

Comment: @shrys Finally my issue has been solved, It was a very small change. The issue was my keyup event was being triggered. I couldnt find why it was getting called, so i put a condition to check for the class name in the input field of the Dropdown Method.

Comment: the issue wasn't the dropdown, kudos, you could throttle the keyup function as well if you wanted to

Comment: Yes i have done the same. The performance is way too good even for a LARGE Data.